# Replace local host file modification with remote. Proxy server or something else?

Tags: centos, proxy, centos-6, hosts-file

I need to find a solution for a problem described below (both servers running CentOS 6)

My goal is to have visible website to the public where a client will type own domain name mydomain.com and then that server will display staging site located on IP a.b.c.d (site is coded as mydomain.com)

In a real world tech savvy client will change windows host file and point mydomain.com to a.b.c.d but there are not much of that kind of clients or some of them have security measurements which doesn't allow to change host file.

Can I do that with a proxy server and modified /etc/host file pointing particular domain name to proper IP ([example](http://www.webpagedeveloper.me/drupal_archive/blog/how-access-websites-different-ips-same-url-same-computer-web-development-purposes.html))? Or do I need to take another way? Ideal choice it will be something like Hide My Ass offers.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a DNS entry like `staging.mydomain.com` and make the client look at that.

Another way would be to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) on the server, in that case you wouldn't have to talk to the client...

In that case, you're going to want to do something like this on Server A:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName owncloud.mydomain.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.10:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.10:80/
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Depending on your application you may need to make use of one or all of the following:

```
X-Forwarded-For - The IP address of the client.
X-Forwarded-Host - The original host requested by the client in the Host HTTP request header.
X-Forwarded-Server - The hostname of the proxy server.
```

Take a look at the [mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) for more tips and tricks.

**References**

[Using Apache with virtual hosts and mod_proxy](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+Apache+with+virtual+hosts+and+mod_proxy)

[Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/510758/how-to-pass-a-request-from-one-apache-server-to-another)

Comment: Problem is that staging and production site is usually somewhere else (different IPs) so there is not way to use mod_rewrite on the server. Also use subdomain due to it will require to query site with replacing `staging.mydomain.com` to `mydomain.com`. Ideal choice it will be something like Hide My Ass offers.

Comment: Edited my answer